# Retrieve elements height dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently try to write a toggle menu script.

Most of the futures are fine, but...

Here's my bin:

https://jsbin.com/rabiporoji/edit?html,css,js,console,output

I use media query to make a different layout,

the idea is... I tried to make the menu extend under 500px screen width,

and not to change anything when the screen size is wider than 500px.

But while the screen size stretched from small to wider than 500px,

the toggle menu will still extended if i click th button.

ps(in this case the height is fixed, but in the project i'm workin on they are pics with only width fixed in percentage)

So, I'm wondering if there's any way to retrieve the elements height dynamically, every time I change the window size.

I know there might be some js libraries and solve this problem in ease.

But I really wanna know some js basis before I start using those.

TY for your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  let height = document.getElementById('thing').offsetHeight;
  console.log('offsetHeight',offsetHeight)
});
```